# How to express one image in terms of another one

Tags: image-processing, decomposition, pca, svd

I have two (black and white) images of identical size - let's say `128x128` pixels. I'm interested in expressing `Im2` in terms of components of `Im1` such that as opposed to specifying `Im2`, I can specify some values (less than number of pixels in `Im2`, otherwise what's the point) which, together with the knowledge of `Im1` would allow me to construct an approximation of `Im2`. Let me demonstrate by giving you my first idea (which, spoiler alert, didn't work). In pythonish pseudocode:

```
# Singular Value Decomposition of Im1 and Im2
U1, S1, V1 = svd(Im1)
# Function to minimise
def fit_function(S):
    Im_fit = U1*diag(S)*V1 
    diff = Im2-Im_fit
    return sqrt(mean(diff^2)) # root-mean-square difference
# Find S which fits Im_fit to Im2
Sfit = myLittleMagicSolver(fit_fun)
```

In other words; use singular value decomposition on `Im1` and `Im2`. Then find numbers other than singular values of `Im1` which together with `U1` and `V1` matrices approximate `Im2`. This way I could specify only 128 values - the main diagonal of the fitted `S` matrix.

This, however, does not work. My fitted images are nowhere close to their target of `Im2`. My question is then, is that a problem someone has tackled already? I am not fussed about the SVD/PCA approach. I just want to be able to express `Im2` in terms of `Im1`.

My intended use is to train a neural network to recognize patterns in my particular dataset where one image is an input to the network, and multiple images are the output. This, of course, makes for a pretty hefty neural net. I, therefore, want to teach the network to recognize the components of the output images in terms of the input instead.

Comment: This is not my area, but I'd say that the answer will depend on the correlation between the two images. Could you explain if there is any?

Comment: @MBaz You can assume none or, at leat, inconsistent. Imagine grayscale of 'lena' (a lady in a hat) and 'mandrill' (a close up face of a baboon).

Comment: With no correlation, I don't see a way -- but if you succeed you'll have an awesome image compressor.

Comment: I think you need to consider the mutual information between the 2 images, as a source and receiver.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz I am not entirely sure what you mean. Could you expand on your suggestion?

Comment: Information theory isn't about how to do things, it is about finding out if you can do things.  You need to come up with a joint probability density that models the 2 images.  One way of doing that would be a black box method like a neural net.  If you can train a neural net to produce image 2, from image 1, and do that for many different pairs, that would seem to be equivalent to what you want.  I don't think you can do that except for a very limited class of problems.  Maybe, sequential frames in a video over a small time window.

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz I have figured it out. You're right, it's hard to do in general, but I found a way to do in in my particular case (see my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer which is good-enough for me. As @Stanley Pawlukiewicz has pointed out in the comments, this is hard to do for a general case when there is little correlation between the images. I, however, want to work with *real images* of *actual things* in the *real world*. This means there will be a lot of low frequency components (that's why [jpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) compression [works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_uNPbdenRs)). If I now formulate the problem as:
$$
I = U_{s} S  V_{s}'
$$
where $I$ is the matrix representing the image, $U_{s}$ and $V_{s}$ are the matrices of the `svd` decomposition of the source image, and we are trying to find $S$. Then, the inverse problem (which is the one we actually want to solve) is:
$$
S = U_{s}^{-1}I(V_{s}')^{-1}
$$
This is the easy part (using [Matlab](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html), [python](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) or otherwise).

I then took a good look at how are the solutions ($S$) to this problem are distributed, and they tend to cluster around the left and upper edge of the S matrix. Therefore, I can approximate S by the subset of S centered around these values. I (slightly arbitrarily) have chosen to use a quarter of a [superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse) to set the cutoff value with a nice constant to play with. I can get S down to 10% of its elements and retain most of the broad features of the image, which is all I wanted.

I've put [my code](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/64756-im2imsvd) up online so you can check it out. Hope this helps someone. :)